# Silverlight using WCF Ria with POCOS gives edit operation error

Tags: silverlight

I have converted an Entity framework project to use POCO objects by removing the entity data model and the domain service and meta data classes.

My silverlight project works as it is showing a datagrid of Employee objects.

I have now added a DataForm and when I modify the "name" property of one of my Employee objects, I get the error:

This EntitySet of type 'TestEmployeesApp.Web.Employee' does not support the 'Edit' operation.

The error occurs on validatingProperty() on the class Entity on the client side.

I checked the metadata on the server side, and all my properties have the attribute Editable(true).

I am using Silverlight 3 with VS2008.

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this link: [RIA Services EntitySet does not support 'Edit' operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445634/ria-services-entityset-does-not-support-edit-opperation), I set the attribute [update] on the update method of my domain service.

In the client generated code I now have :

```
    internal sealed class NorthwindDomainContextEntityContainer : EntityContainer
    {

        public NorthwindDomainContextEntityContainer()
        {
            this.CreateEntitySet<Employee>((EntitySetOperations.Add | EntitySetOperations.Edit));
        }
    }
```

So now my POCO domain service class is a normal .net class that descends from DomainService and has the attribute [update] on the update method.

JD